# Conversion Error of String[] to Integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, type-conversion

```
String bookedDays = month.BookedDays.ToString();
String[] days = bookedDays.Split(',');
String[] DayNumber = day.Split('/');
int DaySpecific = Convert.ToInt16(DayNumber[0]);
```

From my month database, i extract a string containing all days booked (DateTime format) seperated by ',': 
   e.g `{01/01/13 00:00:00, 02/01/13 00:00:00, etc}`.

I then split the day by its '/' paramaters so, in DayNumber[0] i get the value of the day number:
   e.g

```
{01/01/13} becomes Daynumber[0] = '01'; 
DayNumber[1] = '01' DayNumber[2] = '13'
```

Now the part i cannot figure out:
Assigning the int value of DaySpecific from DayNumber[0] using Convert.ToInt32 throws, "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format"

The value of DayNumber[0] is '01', however the conversion method does not take numbers with a starting value of 0.

i've tried DayNumber[0].ToString("N0")  but it always gives an error that the over ride is incorrect.

Does Anyone Know how i can solve this?

(My Apolagese if there is a very simple answer)

EDIT:
Thank you for replying however no solutions as of yet. the {} in {01/01/13} in my example is purely for representing the data set.

i included a try catch and this is the exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int16.Parse(String s)
   at railway.Controllers.MonthController.Index() in c:\Users\simon\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\railway\railway\Controllers\MonthController.cs:line 47
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\37a427fe\5dbf5c62\App_Web_lt1aaagr.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[2276] iisexpress.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Try `Int16.Parse(DayNumber[0])`, that should handle leading zeroes fine. A better option is to get the DateTime as a C# DateTime object and simply get the Day property from it.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16("01")` works OK.

Comment: Don't you need a `DateTime[]`? If so, you can go with `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the day part of the first date in your list (if you have a list of datetime objects):

```
 int DaySpecific = month.BookedDays.First().Day
```

Otherwise:

```
String bookedDays = month.BookedDays.ToString();
String[] dates = bookedDays.Split(',');

int DaySpecific = DateTime.Parse(dates.First()).Day;
```

It would be better if your list was of a type datetime, rather than passing dates around as strings...

Comment: This solution was the one i went for, however i'm sure the others would have worked as just as well. as it turns out, the int16 & int 32 conversion error was due to a semicolon in place of a comma in the booked days dataset on the db. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6):

In the test data you gave, your algorithm will end up using `{01` as day. Which will throw a format exception. Make sure your string is what you believe it is before you convert it.

Answer (score 2):

I think could be more useful to cast that values as DateTime values, as below. You can always extract only day part if you want.

```
var sample = "{01/01/13 00:00:00, 02/01/13 00:00:00}";
var values = Regex.Matches(sample, @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(value =>
    {
        DateTime aux;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value.Value, "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss",
                null, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out aux))
            return aux as DateTime?;

        return null;
    })
    .Where (date => date != null)
    .ToList();

foreach (var date in values)
    Console.WriteLine(date.Value.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine.

```
string bookedDays = "01/01/13 00:00:00, 02/01/13 00:00:00";
string[] days = bookedDays.Split(',');
string[] DayNumber = days[0].Split('/');
int DaySpecific = Convert.ToInt16(DayNumber[0]);
```